# counter that MSB toggles every 2 seconds

Tags: fpga, vhdl, clock, hardware, spartan

I want a counter that the Most significant bit toggles every 2 seconds, and gets values 0 and 1.So for example it will have 0 for 2 seconds and after 1 for another 2 seconds etc..
I need it like that because I will connect the most significant bit to a decoder which will show results on FPGA 3starter (50MHZ/20ns)
Does this will work?

```
 library ieee ;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

----------------------------------------------------

entity counter is

generic(27: natural :=2);
port(   clock:  in std_logic;
    rst:    in std_logic;
    count:  in std_logic;
    Q:  out std_logic_vector(27-1 downto 0)
);
end counter;

----------------------------------------------------

architecture behv of counter is           

    signal Pre_Q: std_logic_vector(27-1 downto 0);

begin

    -- behavior describe the counter

    process(clock, count, clear)
    begin
    if clear = '1' then
        Pre_Q <= Pre_Q - Pre_Q;
    elsif (clock='1' and clock'event) then
        if count = '1' then
        Pre_Q <= Pre_Q + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
    end process;    

    -- concurrent assignment statement
    Q <= Pre_Q(27-1);

end behv;
```

Comment: depends on your clock frequency. NOt the best way to code a counter

Comment: @JonRB my inside  clock on FPGA is 50Mhz/20ns

Comment: @JonRB no it's not duplicate.I am not the same user.

Comment: It isn't necessary that you are the same user, I think it is sufficient that it is the same question. The idea of the stackexchange wiki format is to have a good set of questions and answers, and avoid duplicate questions. The question @JohnRB links to seems to be the same as this question.

Comment: @gbulmer Here It's not 2Hz but 0.5 Hz

Comment: Agreed. In one it may say `max_count: natural := 100_000_000` and in the other `max_count: natural := 400_000_000`. However that alone doesn't seem enough difference to justify a new question. It might have been helpful to ask for a review of your VHDL, e.g. "Review VHDL for 2Hz counter", instead of ask a very similar question, and risking a 'close'. Just my $0.02

Comment: @user  to code to make a 2Hz strobe and a 0.5Hz strobe or any arbitary stroke is not that much different once the method is known

Comment: @JonRB Okay but actually I didn't wanted to divide clock..I wanted a counter that MSB will toggle every 2 seconds. It's not the same.

Comment: @user clock divider, counter... result is the same. you end up with a strobe at a lower rate. A counter is one way todo it: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708301/making-a-clock-divider  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053008/vhdl-clock-divider-counter-duty-cycle  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97301/clock-divider-vhdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, so I'm going to give you the answer here. Let me know if you have any further questions.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

----------------------------------------------------

entity counter is

generic (
  width: natural := 27;
  max_count: natural := 100_000_000     -- 50 MHz / 0.5 Hz
);
port (
  clock:  in std_logic;
  rst:    in std_logic;
  count:  in std_logic;
  Q:      out std_logic
);
end counter;

----------------------------------------------------

architecture behv of counter is           

  signal prescaler: std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
  signal pre_Q : std_logic;

begin

    -- behavior describe the counter

  process (clock, count, clear)
  begin
    if clear = '1' then
      prescaler <= (others => '0');
      pre_Q <= '0';
    elsif (clock='1' and clock'event) then
      if count = '1' then
        if prescaler = max_count then
          -- This happens every 2 seconds; toggle the output flip-flop.
          prescaler <= (others => '0');
          pre_Q <= not pre_Q;
        else
          prescaler <= prescaler + 1;
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;    

    -- concurrent assignment statement
    Q <= pre_Q;

end behv;
```

Comment: The `count` input was in your original code, so I kept it. It functions as an "enable" signal for the counting, so you would ordinarily just tie it high. Yes, `Q` is the output that toggles every 2 seconds.

Comment: You copied that code from [the question that @JonRB cited](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61422/how-to-divide-50mhz-down-to-2hz-in-vhdl-on-xilinx-fpga).

Comment: Yes but I have edited it.

Comment: BUT the principal is the same. asking for a 2Hz strobe isn't much different from asking for a 0.5Hz strobe

Comment: @DaveTweed are you sure that this will work ?? it will show 1 or 0 because I want to get the MSB for seven segment displays.

Comment: I'm sorry -- since you said "toggle", I assumed that MSB meant "most significant *bit*". If you meant something different, you need to be clearer in your original problem statement about what the output actually needs to be. Are you saying that you want a 4-bit value that increments every 2 seconds?

Comment: Don't use acronyms, please spell it out. Edit your question to show exactly what output you expect from this module.

Comment: OK, then yes, the module in my answer does what you want. The `Q` output toggles every 2 seconds.

Comment: @DaveTweed may I ask you something I have an inside enable signal that during the process of the calculation of my results is U when the results are done it gets value 1.But because I am going to connect this enable signal to my seven segment component (fpga,decoder) I will have any problem with that U??(if yes) Is there any way to make the signal stays at 0 during the process?

Comment: You need to assign a value to that enable signal when reset is asserted.